# Why is the state of an LFSR not output?

Tags: lfsr

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) LFSRs are used as PRGs but due to their linearity they are easy to cryptanalyze. Also, using [Berlekamp-Massey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm) consecutive output bits allow reconstruction of the internal LFSR state (I think the rule was something like $2n$ bits for state size $n$).

Now my question is a much more profane one. Given the following diagram for how an LFSR works doesn't it simply output its state and, therefore become trivially predictable?
[image]

Comment: Actually, the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm assumes you *don't* know the feed back terms.  Yes, if you do, it's trivial; if you don't, Berlekamp-Massey makes it trivial

Comment: Wow, they're even more terrible than I could reasonably imagine. ;)

Comment: "Terrible" isn't very objective.  They are certainly unfit for some uses, but they have properties that are desirable for others.

Comment: @Elias, do you have any comments on the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LFSRs are very useful as building blocks of ciphers, with some nonlinearity introduced. For example Trivium is a very strong and fast cipher, which includes a little amount of quadratic nonlinearity in 3 coupled LFSRs.

An example of bad use of LFSRs--and by no means the only one--is the A5 series of ciphers, of GSM fame, where majority clocking does not include enough nonlinearity/unpredictability.

Comment: Well, the feedback function of Trivium is not really linear so it's a little odd. I agree that shift registers can be interesting building blocks as long as sufficient nonlinearity is introduced.